# Why can't I find Amazon.Lambda.Core?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm new to Amazon Lamba, so this may be a newb question. I've downloaded and installed the Amazon SDK and created an new project in Visual Studio.

The [Lamba Programming Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html) talks about adding a Lambda serializer, which is in the Amazon.Lambda.Core namespace, however I just can't seem to find it. I've added the AWSSDK.Core.dll and AWSSDK.Lamba.dll assembly references, but the Amazon.Lambda.Core namespace is nowhere to be found.

[image: AWS Object Model]

In addition, the [Amazon API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) does not have an Amazon.Lamba.Core namespace.

[image: Amazon API Reference]

What have I misunderstood here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: The only reference to `Amazon.Lambda.Core` in the documentation you referred to talks about it as a *library*, not a namespace. And it exists as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Core/) - what makes you think it's a namespace?

Comment: You need the [Visual Studio toolkit](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/). It gives you a new project type. That's the easiest way to create lambda projects.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. It took a bit of figuring out, but I rebuilt my project targetting .Net core, fetched the libraries from NuGet, and now it seems to be working. :)